# java: NoClassDefFoundError when upgrading problem-spring-web dependency from v0.27.0 to v0.29.1 in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test

I am working on a Spring Boot project where I am using the **problem-spring-web** dependency for exception handling.

Here is my **ControllerAdvice**:

```
package com.example.demo.error;

//... other imports ...

@ControllerAdvice
public class SpringBootProblemHandling implements ProblemHandling {

    // ... class content ...

    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleGenericException(
          Exception exception,
          NativeWebRequest request) {
        
        //... method implementation ...
    }
}
```

I also have a corresponding test class:

```
package com.example.demo.error;

//... other imports ...

@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SpringBootProblemHandlingTest {

    private SpringBootProblemHandling problemHandling = new SpringBootProblemHandling();

    private ServletWebRequest request = new ServletWebRequest(new MockHttpServletRequest());

    @Test
    public void handleGenericException() {
        ResponseEntity<Problem> problemRE = problemHandling.handleGenericException(new Exception(), request);

        assertEquals(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, problemRE.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

When using the dependency *org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.27.0*, the test runs with no problem, but when I change the *problem-spring-web* version to ***0.29.1***, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/HttpStatusCode
```

This error occurs at the line where the **SpringBootProblemHandling** object is created in the test class:

```
private SpringBootProblemHandling problemHandling = new SpringBootProblemHandling();
```

I have checked:

1. if there is any breaking change in the release notes between the two versions but couldn’t find any information related to this issue.
2. tried not to instantiate **SpringBootProblemHandling** directly using the new keyword, instead to use auto wire but this also did not help

Comment: What version of Spring/Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: I am using spring-boot v2.5.15

Comment: On the GitHub repo they suggest Spring Boot 2 users to use 0.27.0, whereas for Spring Boot 3 they recommend >= 0.28.0 which was published earlier this year.

Did you check if your problem-spring-web is still compatible with your Spring Boot version?

Comment: @FrankW You are right, my bad it is mentioned in here https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web#:~:text=Spring%205%20(or%20Spring%20Boot%202)%20users%20may%20use%20version%200.27.0

Comment: did that resolve it for you though?

Comment: @FrankW Yes, using version 0.27.0 works since I was using spring-boot v2.5.15